# How can I format outer table but not inner table

Tags: html, css

I have a table nested inside another table. I want to give the outer table cells a border but not the inner table cells. All proper css and html comments aside, how can I style the outer cells but not the inner cells?

css

```
#table1 td
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

html

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>Outer table</td>
        <td><table>
            <tr>
                <td>Inner table</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/

**EDIT**

This is the desired effect, #table2 http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/4/

I could do the following, but I was trying to keep it all in the css.

```
<table id="table2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Outer table</td>
        <td><table>
            <tr>
                <td>Inner table</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Inherited project, I'm just trying to fix one thing and I want to change as little as possible and get it done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
#table1 td {
    border: solid 1px black;
}

#table1 table td {
    border: none;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/3/

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) (`>`) like this:

```
#table1 > tbody > tr > td
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kbVH2/1/)

Please note that in the demo I also added the `tbody` element. Some browsers will add it automatically if you omit it (like my Chrome), others might not, so for consistency, I normally add it to make sure it is not breaking my selectors.

I would not say this is your best choice in every situation, but a possible alternative.

**Note:** Internet Explorer 6 does not support the child selector. See [Quirksmode CSS 2.1 Selectors Compatibility Table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#CSS2).

Comment: Are there any issues with browser compatibility using this method? Like IE7+ only?

Comment: IE6 does not support it. I add this information to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#table1 td
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}
#table1 td table td
{
 /*NORMAL INSIDE TABLE CSS HERE*/
}
```

put what ever you want the inside table to do inside the second selector. The inside table automatically inherits the outer ones css, but you can override it

Comment: I don't want to style the inner table at all. I want the outer table to have a border but leave the inner table untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving them different `class` IDs and drive the CSS from those classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
#table1 tr td{
//The table 1 css
}
#table1 tr td table tr td
{
//The second table
}
```

This should be exact to the second table!